# Null pointer exception thrown when using libphonenumber in unit test

Tags: android, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, mockito, libphonenumber

[image]I am using 'michaelrocks.libphonenumber.android' to format and validate phone numbers. When I run the app it works fine.

I wrote two tests but both of them fail with Null Pointer exception. Not able to figure out why there is an exception.

Am I doing anything fundamentally wrong here?. You help suggestions are much appreciated.

This is the method which thorws a null pointer exception.

```
 private static Phonenumber.PhoneNumber getPhoneNumberObj(final String phone, final String code, PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil){
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumberObj = null;
        try {
            String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(code));
            /**THIS IS WHERE THERE IS A NULL POINTER EXCEPTION**/
            phoneNumberObj = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phone, isoCode);         
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone parsing error", e);
        }
        return phoneNumberObj;
    }
```

here is the full code.

Validator class

imports and methods

```
import io.michaelrocks.libphonenumber.android.PhoneNumberUtil;
import io.michaelrocks.libphonenumber.android.Phonenumber;

public static boolean validatePhone(final String phone, final String code, Context context) {
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(context);
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
        try{
            phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberObj(phone, code, phoneNumberUtil);
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return phoneNumber != null && phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber);
    }

    public static String getFormattedPhoneNumber(final String phone, final String code, Context context) {
        String formatedPhoneNumber = "";
        PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil = PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(context);
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumber = null;
        try {
            phoneNumber = getPhoneNumberObj(phone, code, phoneNumberUtil);
            if(phoneNumber != null && phoneNumberUtil.isValidNumber(phoneNumber)){
                formatedPhoneNumber = phoneNumberUtil.format(phoneNumber, PhoneNumberUtil.PhoneNumberFormat.E164);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone parsing error", e);
        }
        return formatedPhoneNumber;
    }

    private static Phonenumber.PhoneNumber getPhoneNumberObj(final String phone, final String code, PhoneNumberUtil phoneNumberUtil){
        Phonenumber.PhoneNumber phoneNumberObj = null;
        try {
            String isoCode = phoneNumberUtil.getRegionCodeForCountryCode(Integer.parseInt(code));
            phoneNumberObj = phoneNumberUtil.parse(phone, isoCode);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Phone parsing error", e);
        }
        return phoneNumberObj;
    }
```

My unit tests

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ValidatorTest {

    @Mock
    Context mMockContext;

    private final String VALID_PHONE_NUMBER = "07455658798";
    private final String VALID_CODE = "+44";
    private final String VALID_FORMATTED_PHONE_NUMBER = "+447455658798";

    @Test
    public void validatePhone() throws Exception {
        assertThat(Validator.validatePhone(VALID_PHONE_NUMBER, VALID_CODE, mMockContext), is(true));
    }

    @Test
    public void getFormattedPhoneNumber() throws Exception {
        String result = Validator.getFormattedPhoneNumber(VALID_PHONE_NUMBER, VALID_CODE, mMockContext);
        assertThat(result, is(VALID_FORMATTED_PHONE_NUMBER));
    }
}
```

Comment: Seems you need to show this one's implementation: `PhoneNumberUtil.createInstance(context);` as well.

Comment: Hi Bartosz I have that in both validatePhone and getFormattedPhoneNumber methods

Comment: Yes, and probably it returns `null`.

Comment: I did have a look and it is not null

Comment: Well, doesn't the stack trace show you what is null?

Comment: During the unit test the PhoneNumberUtil object does not seem right. I have updated the question with the screen shots of both normal run and during unit test run. Object is not as required. what might be causing this. any idea please. Is mockContext not enough.

Comment: Find the stack trace to identify what is `null`. Otherwise it's only guessing.